# FFMPEG waiting for images in image2pipe mode

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I'm creating a Node JS application which takes an m-jpeg image stream, and constructs an MPEG-1 stream on the fly. I'm leveraging fluent-ffmpeg at the moment. The steam is intended to be continuous and long-lived. The images flow in freely at a constant framerate.

Unfortunately, using `image2pipe` and input `-vcodec mjpeg`, it seems like ffmpeg needs to wait until all the images are ready before processing begins.

Is there any way to have ffmpeg pipe in and pipe out immediately, as images arrive?

Here is my current Node JS code:

```
var proc = new ffmpeg({ source: 'http://localhost:8082/', logger: winston, timeout: 0 })
  .fromFormat('image2pipe')
  .addInputOption('-vcodec', 'mjpeg')
  .toFormat('mpeg1video')
  .withVideoBitrate('800k')
  .withFps(24)
  .writeToStream(outStream);
```

And the ffmpeg call it generates:

```
ffmpeg -f image2pipe -vcodec mjpeg -i - -f mpeg1video -b:v 800k -r 24 -y http://127.0.0.1:8082/
```

Comment: I think it doesn't wait until *all* frames have arrived, but it waits until 5 MB of image data has arrived, as that is the default `-probesize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a live stream, try switching `image2pipe` for `rawvideo`:

```
.fromFormat('rawvideo')
.addInputOption('-pixel_format', 'argb')
.addInputOption('-video_size', STREAM_WIDTH + 'x' + STREAM_HEIGHT)
```

This will encode the video at very low latency, instantly.

You can remove `.fromFormat('image2pipe')` and `.addInputOption('-vcodec', 'mjpeg')`.